# Need a good app for writing Android applications on phone itself

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow

I am a beginner in Android programming,  and have started very recently. I mainly used to work on my computer (loaded with android SDK and versions 4.0 to 6.0 and having android studio and Eclipse IDE).

But, currently, for a long time, it is not possible for me to sit at my computer. Is there any good app where I can write, compile and run applications on phone itself?

I have a Samsung Galaxy On7 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow.

**Update: please suggest anything but the AIDE IDE available in Google play store.**